# How does a Hive timestamp string look like?

Tags: hive

To load data in a Hive table with a timestamp format, I'm not sure what formats are allowed. I looked this up online and I can see a lot of examples without the fractional part.

Can someone tell me whether Hive will accept the text as timestamp if the input text is in the following formats-

```
1) 'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS FFFFFF' 
2) 'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS FFFFFFFFF'
3) 'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS'
4) 'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS,FFFFFFFFF'
5) 'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS,FFFFFF'
6) 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FFFFFFFFF'
```

FF is for fractional seconds I believe. MI is for minutes. Out of 1 to 6, which ones would be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Hive supports only till seconds. Even the unix_timestamp() method returns only till seconds omitting the milliseconds part.

The best option is to write a UDF using the java simpledateformat based on the way you need the timestamp to be represented.

Comment: Here is a link that says Hive supports nanoseconds - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-timestamp